# my datetime string is not recognized as valid DateTime format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've completely stumped on this one. Trying to convert my user input string datetime (format dd-mm-yyyy) into a DateTime object, but unable to convert and keep getting above error.

if I try to use:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "dd-MMM-YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

where dob is string input from user in dd-mm-yyyy format.

It won't give error although conversion is different.

For eg;

Input : 22-10-1984
Output : 1-22-1984

Comment: You have three MMM instead of two. Three M's are for the string name of the Months like October.

Comment: also YYYY is not the correct string to represent a 4 digits year. _yyyy_ is the right one

Comment: And when you try _mm_ (lower case) you are asking for minutes not months. The [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) are a mandatory read

Comment: @Vishnu check this 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/gb4mjy

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the  `Convert.ToDateTime` method if `ParseExact` method isn't suitable for you. Just check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Use proper datetime format.
>
> MM- month. yyyy- years.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.